# Multiple subprocesses take a lot of time to complete

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, tesseract, popen

I have a single process that is run using `subprocess` module's `Popen`:

```
result = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract','mypic.png','myop'])
st = time()
while result.poll() is None:
    sleep(0.001)
en = time()

print('Took :'+str(en-st))
```

Which results in:

```
Took :0.44703030586242676
```

Here, a `tesseract` call is made to process an image `mypic.png`(attached) and output the OCR's result to `myop.txt`.

[image]

Now I want this to happen on multiple processes on behalf of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606867/what-is-the-difference-between-multiprocessing-and-subprocess/13606946?noredirect=1#comment94493006_13606946)  (or see [this directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call)), so the code is here:

```
lst = []
for i in range(4):
    lst.append(subprocess.Popen(['tesseract','mypic.png','myop'+str(i)]))

i=0
l = len(lst)
val = 0 
while(val!=(1<<l)-1):
    if(lst[i].poll() is None):
        print('Waiting for :'+str(i))
        sleep(0.01)
    else:
        temp = val
        val = val or (1<<(i))
        if(val!=temp):
            print('Completed for :'+temp)
    i = (i+1) %l
```

What this code does is make 4 calls to `tesseract`, save the process objects in a list `lst`, iterate through all of these objects until **all** of them are completed. Explanation for the implementation of the infinite loop is given at the bottom.

The problem here is that the latter program is taking a hell lot of time to complete. It is continuously waiting for the processes to complete using `poll()` function, which is `None` until the process has not been completed. This should not have happened. It should have taken a little more than 0.44s only. Not something like 10 minutes! Why is this happening?

I came to this specific error by digging into `pytesseract`, which was taking a lot of time when run parallely using `multiprocessing` or `pathos`. So this is a scaled down version of a much bigger issue. My question on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468446/pytesseract-call-working-very-slow-when-used-along-with-multiprocessing).

---

Explanation for the infinite loop:
`val` is 0 initially. It is ORed with the `2^i` when the ith process completes. So, if there are 3 processes, then if the first process(i=0) is completed then `2^0 = 1` is OR'ed with `val` making it 1. With second and third processes being completed, `val` becomes `2^0` | `2^1` | `2^2` = 7. And `2^3-1` is also 7. So the loop works until `val` equals `2^{number of processes}-1`.

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866651/python-concurrent-futures-using-subprocess-with-a-callback), how to run multiple subprocesses easily in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the faq](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#can-i-increase-speed-of-ocr) (with my emphasis):

> Tesseract 4 also uses up to four CPU threads while processing a page, so it will be faster than Tesseract 3 for a single page.
>
> If your computer has only two CPU cores, then running four threads will slow down things significantly and it would be better to use a single thread or maybe a maximum of two threads! **Using a single thread eliminates the computation overhead of multithreading and is also the best solution for processing lots of images by running one Tesseract process per CPU core**.
>
> Set the maximum number of threads using the environment variable OMP_THREAD_LIMIT.
>
> To disable multithreading, use OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1.

Therefore, if you wish to run multiple tesseract processes concurrently, you may wish to decrease (or experiment with) OMP_THREAD_LIMIT.
The optimal value depends on how many threads your machine can support concurrently.

For example, on my machine:

```
import subprocess
import time
import os 

t = time.perf_counter()    
tasks = [('mypic.png', 'myop{}'.format(i)) for i in range(4)]
procs = [subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', infile, outfile], env={'OMP_THREAD_LIMIT':'1'})
         for infile, outfile in tasks]
for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
print('{} s'.format(time.perf_counter()-t))
```

completes in 0.220 seconds, whereas the same code without `env={'OMP_THREAD_LIMIT':'1'}`
typically takes between 3.1 -- 5.1 seconds, with a lot of variation between runs.

---

To get your code working, use the [binary bitwise or operator, `|`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) instead of the [logical or operator, `or`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
val = val | (1 << (i))
```

For example,

```
import time
import subprocess
lst = []
for i in range(4):
    lst.append(subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', 'mypic.png', 'myop'+str(i)]))

i = 0
l = len(lst)
val = 0
counter = 0
while(val != (1 << l)-1):
    if(lst[i].poll() is None):
        time.sleep(0.001)
    else:
        temp = val
        val = val | (1 << (i))
        if(val != temp):
            print('Completed for : {}'.format(i))
    i = (i+1) % l

    counter += 1
print('{} iterations'.format(counter))
```

prints output like

```
Completed for : 1
Completed for : 2
Completed for : 3
Completed for : 0
6121 iterations
```

Notice the loop still iterates thousands of times, mainly while `lst[i].poll()` returns `None`,
but also because `i = (i+1) % l` can revisit the same value multiple times.
If one iteration takes 0.001s, then 6121 iterations will take 6.121s. So the `while` loop is complicated and not very fast.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: For anyone looking for the exact command: `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 tesseract <image-name> <output-file/stream> <optional-configurations>`

Comment: ...or, to enable it from pytesseract on any command your app might call: `import os` then `os.environ['OMP_THREAD_LIMIT'] = '1'`.